# communicate with ADSF using SAML2.0 using C#

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1, adfs4.0

I am totally new on ADFS and SAML2.0. I don't know more and want to check whether component space can meet my requirement or not.

Background:
we're using the windows AD help to store the user info using for authorization. So, we need to implement SSO function with their ADFS4.0 version Service with Saml2.0.

TODO:
Need to connect the ADFS server and get the token and authorize the same for SSO once user login to adsf login page implement this we have metadata XML file.

AS We dnt have any idea how to start working with it.

> Technology need to use is with .NET core 3.1

**Any help will be appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ComponentSpace.

Look [here](https://authory.com/RoryBraybrook?collection=_all&text=componentspace&view=thumbnail&sort=relevance_DESC) for some samples.

In addition, they have very good documentation.

Download the free trial and look at the step by step docs. for ADFS.